# Using Kendo Listview to replace Html Form

Tags: kendo-ui

Is anybody using Kendo UI Listview to replace the Html Form?

Since the Listview has its datasource and both template and edittemplate, I think the Listview can be used as the normal Html Form behavior: create, view, and edit.

May I get further idea on this?

Comment: This is a layout component.  You can use it to layout your inputs and buttons to trigger deletes, etc, but you're still going to end up writing html.

Comment: Hi Joe I think the good thing is the Listview itself is MVVM, if using MVVM for a Form by myself, I think it is super difficult to handle the dropdownlist and some widget in Kendo, which should be much smarter